# Convert a Region latitudeDelta / longitudeDelta into an approximate zoomLevel

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use the great `react-native-maps` from Airbnb on a `react-native` app.

I got a list of markers on a JSON file where each of these markers have a property `zoom` which is a integer of an approximate zoom level where the marker should display / hide on the map.

Is there a way based on the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` of a `Region` to get an approximate double/integer of the current zoom level as we have on Google Maps (1 to 20) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok I come with an handy solution, I don't know if we can do better.

I added the `onRegionChange` event to retrieve the region, then I use some math :

```js
    <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={this.state.region}
        onRegionChange={region => {
            clearTimeout(this.timerForMap)
            this.timerForMap = setTimeout(() => {
                this.showMarkers(region)
            }, 100)
        }}>
        ...
```

Then :

```js
    showMarkers(region) {
        let zoom = Math.round(Math.log(360 / region.longitudeDelta) / Math.LN2)
        ...
    }
```

If someone have a better way to do it, feel free to comment !

Thanks.

Comment: This is also how I get the zoom level.

Comment: you can use this to calculate the region for a given zoom `const distanceDelta = Math.exp(Math.log(360) - (zoom * Math.LN2));`

Comment: Where do we use this zoom variable

Answer (score 4):

you can get the zoom level from getCamera() using onRegionChange in MapView

```
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(''); //initiates variable zoom

const getZoom = async () => {
  const coords = await mapRef.getCamera();
  setZoom(coords.center.zoom); // sets variable zoom the value under coords.center.zoom
}

<MapView>
ref = {(ref) => mapRef = ref}
 onRegionChange = {() => {getZoom();}}
</MapView>
```